# Sklearn CountVectorizer vocabulary is not complete

Tags: regex, dictionary, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Consider the following example:

```
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=1, min_df=0,
                                max_features=None,
                                stop_words=None)

all_docs = ['ETH:0x0000 00:17:A4:77:9C:04 09:00:2B:00:00:05 0 PortA Unknown 755 0 45300 ETH FirstHourDay_21 LastHourDay_23 duration_6911 ThreatScore_nan ThreatCategory_nan False Anomaly_False',
            'ETH:0x0000 00:17:A4:77:9C:04 09:00:2B:00:00:05 2 PortC Unknown 774 0 46440 ETH FirstHourDay_21 LastHourDay_23 duration_6911 ThreatScore_nan ThreatCategory_nan False Anomaly_False',
 'ETH:0x0000 00:17:A4:77:9C:0A 09:00:2B:00:00:05 0 PortA Unknown 752 0 45120 ETH FirstHourDay_21 LastHourDay_23 duration_6913 ThreatScore_nan ThreatCategory_nan False Anomaly_False',
 'ICMP 10.6.224.1 71.6.165.200 0 PortA 192 IP-ICMP 1 1 70 ICMP FirstHourDay_22 LastHourDay_22 duration_0 ThreatScore_122,127 ThreatCategory_21,23 True Anomaly_True',
 'ICMP 10.6.224.1 71.6.165.200 2 PortC 192 IP-ICMP 1 1 70 ICMP FirstHourDay_22 LastHourDay_22 duration_0 ThreatScore_122,127 ThreatCategory_21,23 True Anomaly_True',
 'ICMP 10.6.224.1 185.93.185.239 0 PortA 192 IP-ICMP 1 1 70 ICMP FirstHourDay_22 LastHourDay_22 duration_0 ThreatScore_127 ThreatCategory_23 True Anomaly_True']

tf_v = tf_vectorizer.fit(all_docs)
```

The obtained vocabulary is:

```
{'0a': 0,
 '185': 1,
 '239': 2,
 '45120': 3,
 '45300': 4,
 '46440': 5,
 '752': 6,
 '755': 7,
 '774': 8,
 '93': 9,
 'duration_6913': 10,
 'threatcategory_23': 11,
 'threatscore_127': 12}
```

Some words are missing from the vocabulary such as `ETH, FirstHourDay_22, Anomaly_True`.

Why is this? how can I have a full vocabulary?

EDIT: 
The error is probably due to the `token_pattern` value in CountVectorizer

EDIT:
I suggest to riconsider the problem with the following variable:

`all_docs=['ETH0x0000 0017A4779C04 09002B000005 0 PortA Unknown 755 0 45300 FirstHourDay21 LastHourDay23 duration6911 ThreatScorenan ThreatCategorynan False AnomalyFalse',
 'ETH0x0000 0017A4779C04 09002B000005 2 PortC Unknown 774 0 46440 FirstHourDay21 LastHourDay23 duration6911 ThreatScorenan ThreatCategorynan False AnomalyFalse',
 'ETH0x0000 0017A4779C0A 09002B000005 0 PortA Unknown 752 0 45120 FirstHourDay21 LastHourDay23 duration6913 ThreatScorenan ThreatCategorynan False AnomalyFalse',
 'ICMP 10.6.224.1 71.6.165.200 0 PortA 192 IP-ICMP 1 1 70 FirstHourDay22 LastHourDay22 duration0 ThreatScore122,127 ThreatCategory21,23 True AnomalyTrue',
 'ICMP 10.6.224.1 71.6.165.200 2 PortC 192 IP-ICMP 1 1 70 FirstHourDay22 LastHourDay22 duration0 ThreatScore122,127 ThreatCategory21,23 True AnomalyTrue',
 'ICMP 10.6.224.1 185.93.185.239 0 PortA 192 IP-ICMP 1 1 70 FirstHourDay22 LastHourDay22 duration0 ThreatScore127 ThreatCategory23 True AnomalyTrue']`

Comment: The default `token_pattern` used to initialize the `CountVectorizer` object seems to work as expected. Try the regular expression `r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b"` in the website (https://regex101.com/) and paste your strings. It does what you expect

Comment: Then the problem is not the regex.   What may the problem be?

Comment: I am trying to understand from where does your first vocabulary term come from. There is no `'0a'` in any of your strings.

Comment: I suggest you to try with the new definiition of all_docs. This does not contains problematic chars like `:` or `_`

Comment: Actually the `'0a'` came from lowering the `"0A"` in the string `'00:17:A4:77:9C:0A'` when splitted by the tokenizer (i.e. ignoring `:`)

Comment: ``max_df=1`` means only consider tokens that appear only in a single document (see issue tracker).

Comment: @AndreasMueller, but then `max_df` is multiplied by `n_doc` the number of documents in the corpus. So in the method `_limit_features ()` does it mean "keep only documents that appear in all documents ?" (`max_df = 0.5` would have been "appearing in at most half of the documents" ?)

Comment: @AndreasMueller The error is now clear but I definitively think that there should be a warning for values 0 and 1 used as int. I cannot find my issue on github anymore.

Comment: @MMF Only for floating point numbers, not ints.